# Facebook Like Box doesn't show correct number of faces

Tags: facebook, interface, facebook-likebox

I've tried everything basically, and even on facebooks site it doesn't work right -

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Type in page "venula" and you'll see it doesn't show the right amount of faces, but other pages like "microsoft" do.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/164256206995464) *similar* problem...although it's very unlikely, but maybe your fans never made it public that they liked that page - or they don't exist anymore on facebook.

Try logging in as your page - see the arrow next to Home on facebook.com and click on `use facebook as page`. You're able to see all the likes of your page, **on** your page. Are there more faces - to see click on the friends button on the top left corner on facebook.com? 
Maybe the like-box changed now too ?!

Other than that, it really might be a bug! Wait a few more days and send in a bug report if the problem persists!